# Invocation of Win32_Service UserControlService not working

Tags: c#, service, wmi

I'm using WMI to install/start/stop etc. services on a remote machine. This is working nicely, only the invocation of the `UserControlService` seems to be a problem.

I know that it would also be possible to impersonate a user and then use the ServiceController class, but as I've already got all other methods I would rather keep the WMI code and get my method to send service control requests working.

Following code:

```
 public static string SendServiceControlRequest(string remoteHost, string serviceName, string username,
                                                 string password, int request)

    {
        ConnectionOptions theConnection = new ConnectionOptions();
        theConnection.Username = username;
        theConnection.Password = password;
        ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", remoteHost), theConnection);
        using (ManagementObject theClass = new ManagementObject(theScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Service"),
                                                           new ObjectGetOptions())) // causes an ArgumentOutOfRangeException (Parametername: path)
        {
            using (ManagementBaseObject inParams = theClass.GetMethodParameters("UserControlService"))
            {
                inParams["ControlCode"] = (Byte)request;

                ManagementBaseObject outParams = theClass.InvokeMethod("UserControlService", inParams, null);
                return outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Throws a `System.Management.ManagementException` complaining about invalid parameters (with request of 150, which should work). The exception is thrown on `theClass.InvokeMethod` I'm not sure why this happen, I'm getting the description of the method from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393952(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: Working version with the corrections by Hans Passant:

```
  public static bool SendServiceControlRequest(string remoteHost, string serviceName, string username,
                                                 string password, int request)

    {
        ConnectionOptions theConnection = new ConnectionOptions();
        theConnection.Username = username;
        theConnection.Password = password;
        ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", remoteHost),
                                                          theConnection);
        string servicePath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName);
        ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(servicePath);
        using (ManagementObject theClass = new ManagementObject(theScope, path,
                                                           new ObjectGetOptions()))
        {
            using (ManagementBaseObject inParams = theClass.GetMethodParameters("UserControlService"))
            {
                inParams["ControlCode"] = (Byte)request;

                ManagementBaseObject outParams = theClass.InvokeMethod("UserControlService", inParams, null);
                return outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString() == "0";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does calling `UserControlService`, with a value of `150` do?

Comment: Well, I assumed it would send a custom Service Control Request http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685153(v=vs.85).aspx to the windows service... at the Windows Service side I can react on custom commands (e.g. in .NET by overriding the OnCustomCommand method of a service).

Comment: Have you seen [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1dbe4995-ce73-4f01-8d9a-6cf1650bce8a/wmi-c-managementclassinvokemethod-failure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1dbe4995-ce73-4f01-8d9a-6cf1650bce8a/wmi-c-managementclassinvokemethod-failure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a bug in your code.  You correctly added a *serviceName* argument to your method but you forgot to actually use it.  That's important, you really do have to be specific about what particular service you send this control code to.

Make it look like this instead:

```
  var path = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName);
  var thePath = new ManagementPath(path);
  var theClass = new ManagementObject(theScope, thePath, null);
  // etc...
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that really does seem to be a bug (a silly one). With the corrected code I get a new Exception: ArgumentOutOfRangeException (for parameter path) in the call to the constructor of ManagementClass... do you have an idea why this could be? I posted my code with your corrections in the original question.

Comment: By the way, setting the ObjectGetOptions to null doesn't make a difference (just noticed that your code does that).

Comment: That was the version I tested, it worked well.  ArgumentOutOfRange is raised if path.IsClass or path.IsInstance is *true*.  Check that with the debugger.

Comment: path.IsInstance is true, but I'm unsure what this means when applied to a service. All my other methods using WMI to control services seem to use the same code to generate a ManagementPath.

Comment: You didn't copy my code correctly.  Note how theClass is a **ManagementObject**, not a ManagementClass.

Comment: Hans, thank you very much for your corrections (and your patience when I'm obviously incapable of copy-pasting code correctly) everything works now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`inParams["ControlCode"] = (Byte)request;`

try

`inParams.SetPropertyValue("ControlCode", (Byte)request);`

**EDIT**

Untested, but this seems to be what you might be looking for:

Instead of

```
    using (ManagementBaseObject inParams = theClass.GetMethodParameters("UserControlService"))
    {
        inParams["ControlCode"] = (Byte)request;

        ManagementBaseObject outParams = theClass.InvokeMethod("UserControlService", inParams, null);
        return outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString();
    }
```

Try utilizing the ManagementClass instances (from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1dbe4995-ce73-4f01-8d9a-6cf1650bce8a/wmi-c-managementclassinvokemethod-failure):

```
    foreach (var instance in theClass.GetInstances())
    {
        using (ManagementBaseObject inParams = instance.GetMethodParameters("UserControlService"))
        {
            inParams["ControlCode"] = (Byte)request;

            ManagementBaseObject outParams = instance.InvokeMethod("UserControlService", inParams, null);
            return outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but these seem to be equivalent. With inParams.SetPropertyValue(...) I still get the invalid parameters exception...

Comment: theClass is a ManagementClass, GetInstances seems to return a ManagementObjectCollection, so each instance in the second code snippet would be a ManagementBaseObject... thus not having a GetMethodParameters method. Not quite sure if the second code is a possibility.